# Rails - prefixing route helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am wondering what would be the best way (or indeed any kind of way) to prefix path/url helpers that get generated by Rails?

I.e. I need my `dogs_path` equivalent of having `"extra/path" + dogs_path`

I am not looking to namespace my routes (i.e. `scope '/admin' { #my_routes }`), this is needed specifically to address some reverse proxying issues that I'm having.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply define your route with `as` option like this?

```
get 'dogs' => 'dogs#index', as: 'extra_path_dogs'
```

This will give you:

```
extra_path_dogs GET  /dogs(.:format) dogs#index
```

And, you can use `extra_path_dogs_path` afterwards.

Comment: Ideally I don't want to do that on routes because I want to have some environment specific logic around that functionality (i.e. via config or via monkey patching).  Plus I want to keep my routes restful.  Essentially I want to tap into helper generators, not into routing in general